# Client Server Relationship Confusion

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I have 5 computers that control different hardware.  One of the five is the main controller for the other 4.  I need to send commands from the main controller to the 4 slave controllers over TCPIP.  I have very limited experience with Socket programming.

In the system I have which would be the client and which would be the server?  It would seem to me that in the configuration I have the line between server and client may be skewed.  Both sides need to send and receive commands, is there really a separation of client and server or is that just the convention?  Can I have both endpoints as a client and server at the same time using the same socket?  **Essentially can I have both ends listening and sending requests?**

I'm referencing the example code on MSN.

[Asynchronous Server Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Asynchronous Client Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as socket connections go, who is the client and who is the server is just a matter of who accepts connections (the server) and who initiates a connect request (the client).

Once the connection is established, traffic can go in either direction (both client and server can send and/or receive data).

Answer (score 1):

Your main controller is the Server.  When it comes online it listens for your slaves to announce that they are online.  They do this by connecting to the Server as Clients.  The Server will Accept the connections.

If each slave performs some special function then you should have a message that the client can send to the server that indicates this function.  If all of the slaves are required for the system to function properly then you will need to wait for all of the slaves to announce their distinct functions.

Your Server would then be able to send messages to a distinct Client or broadcast to all Clients.  Each Client would only be able to send messages to the Server.  If client-to-client communication is necessary you would probably implement message forwarding in the Server.  This way, your Clients do not need to know the addresses of the other clients.  They would only need to know their function, which would be used to route the messages to the appropriate Client.

I'm basically saying that you need to define a protocol by which your nodes will to communicate.  This protocol will dictate which one of the nodes will be the Server and which of the nodes will be the Clients.

If your protocol turns out to be more appropriate for peer-to-peer instead of  client-server you might want to consider using UDP instead of TCP.